# Get the number of levels of a categorical variable as a single number in Stata

Tags: stata, levels

I am trying to find a way to get the number of levels of a categorical variable as a single number. For example if I have a variable `X` with 4 levels I need to somehow get that number. If I type `levelsof X` I get the following `1 2 3 4` but I can't get only number 4 from there. Is there a way to do it using the `levelsof` or another command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various commands will give you the number of distinct values, for any kind of variable. ("Categorical variable" is a statistical concept, rather than a Stata concept.)  Perhaps the simplest way to do it for one-off purposes is to ask for a one-way tabulation using `tabulate`. The number of distinct values is then the number of rows in that table, returned as `r(r)`. Note that (1) you can suppress the table itself (which is useful in a program or do file) and (2) missing values are excluded by default:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. qui tab foreign

. ret li

scalars:
                  r(N) =  74
                  r(r) =  2

. qui tab rep78

. ret li

scalars:
                  r(N) =  69
                  r(r) =  5

. qui tab rep78, missing

. ret li

scalars:
                  r(N) =  74
                  r(r) =  6
```

An extended review of this problem, pitched more generally, is available [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042). That paper introduces a `distinct` command. Its uses include direct support for looking at the number of distinct values systematically. `search distinct` in Stata to find a download source for the most recent version.

```
. distinct

              |           Observations
              |         total      distinct
--------------+----------------------------
         make |            74            74
        price |            74            74
          mpg |            74            21
        rep78 |            69             5
     headroom |            74             8
        trunk |            74            18
       weight |            74            64
       length |            74            47
         turn |            74            18
 displacement |            74            31
   gear_ratio |            74            36
      foreign |            74             2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at `r(r)` after `levelsof`:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. levelsof rep78
1 2 3 4 5

. display "rep78 has " `r(r)' " levels."
rep78 has 5 levels.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I use StataMP 14 and the above code does not show up `r(r)`. The help of `levelsof` did not mention about `r(r)` either.